# Semver is too difficult or what’s going on?

Tags: javascript, version, frontend, versioning

I noticed that in JavaScript world something changed over time. Previously backend and frontend used semver approach when it comes to version a library or app. Now, in JS world some and I see more and more libraries or frameworks follow the approach to release major version 2 or even more times per year. Let’s take Angular, Ionic for example. Some of my ex or just colleagues also are using the approach.

Why is that? I am asking this as I am a backend developer but I am about to release a JS - powered library and I am a bit confused how to version this.

Answer (score 1):

They release much more frequently major versions **precisely** to comply with server requirements: they gradually introduce some breaking changes (even if most of the time they are small), therefore release with a new major version.

In the case of Angular, as you notice they plan to release a new major version about every 6 months. The idea is to keep freedom to improve the library without being constantly stuck with full backwards compatibility requirement.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now it is much clearer. However, I see some problems in this approach. If the cycle of the library is quite short (like with Angular), developers will have to spend time on upgrading to a new version, instead of shipping something new. It perfectly works with backend. Plus, there can be LTS releases, however they (Frontend) do not use this possibility.